# Fancybox scroll issue on mobile devices

Tags: jquery, mobile, scroll, fancybox

I am using fancy box, and when fancybox is opened, I want to stop body scroll and with that fancybox scroll should work.

I have below code, which stops body scroll but fancybox scroll is also not working..

```
jQuery(function ($) {
   $("#more_insurance").fancybox({
    closeBtn    : true,
    closeClick  : true,
    scrolling   : 'auto',
    openEffect  : 'elastic',
    closeEffect : 'elastic',
       beforeShow: function(){
        $("body").css({'overflow-y':'hidden'});

        $('body').bind('touchmove.fb', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

         });
        },
         afterClose: function(){
            $("body").css({'overflow-y':'visible'});
        },


       });
});
```

Please help..

Comment: Looks like you are using fancybox2, have you tried upgrading to v3?

Answer (score 0):

Fancybox 2 helpers option locked:true did the trick for me, in fb3 i have scroll issue's